# Vitepress custom theme, multiple layouts for different pages

Tags: vue.js, vitepress

So vitepress is a early WIP and there is currently not much in the way of documentation. I'm curious if there is anyone out there that would be able to help me with this question instead of creating an issue:
Having a homepage layout and a default page layout. I know in vuepress has this option by using the following

```
---
layout: AnotherLayout
---
```

Answer (score 0):

On Vitepress you have 3 already layouts:

- `home`
- `doc` (default)
- `page`

You can set layout of a page (markdown file at `/docs`) using the frontmatter format:

```markdown
---
layout: page
---

# My title

My paragraph lorem ipsum ...
> My blockquote ....
```

If `layout` is not specified, then default `doc` layout will be used.

Of course, you can create layouts without limit. See [Vitepress layout documentation](https://vitepress.vuejs.org/guide/theme-layout.html)

Comment: The link provided does not work and in the current documentation I was not able to find information on multiple layouts. I'm also trying to solve a similar problem. I'd like to have a biog along with the documentation with a completely different layout.